# EntityManager.getResultList() does not return the expected result

Tags: sql, entitymanager

```
select a.AssignAccOwner,a.AssignBillRate,a.AssignPerdiem from orion_db.assignment as a where a.AssignmentId=25
```

I am able to execute the above query successfully . But when I try to execute the same query programatically using entityManager.createnativeQuery I am getting the resultList as 0
Below is the code

```
buff.append("select a.AssignAccOwner,a.AssignBillRate,a.AssignPerdiem from orion_db.assignment as a where a.AssignmentId=25");
                Query q2 = entityManager.createNativeQuery(buff.toString());
        resultList = q2.getResultList();                
        System.out.println("Geting the resultList in dao layer " + q2.getResultList().size());
        System.out.println("Geting the result in dao layer " + resultList.size());
```

This is the result which I get in the log

```
Geting the resultList in dao layer 0
Geting the result in dao layer 0
```

Below is the assignment.java entity class

/**
 * Assignment generated by hbm2java
 */

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "assignment")
    public class Assignment implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Integer assignmentId;       
        private String assignAccOwner;  
        private BigDecimal assignBillRate;


        private String assignPerdiem;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "AssignmentId", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getAssignmentId() {
            return this.assignmentId;
        }

        public void setAssignmentId(Integer assignmentId) {
            this.assignmentId = assignmentId;
        }

        @Column(name = "AssignBillRate", precision = 10)
        public BigDecimal getAssignBillRate() {
            return this.assignBillRate;
        }

        public void setAssignBillRate(BigDecimal assignBillRate) {
            this.assignBillRate = assignBillRate;
        }


        @Column(name = "AssignPerdiem", length = 30)
        public String getAssignPerdiem() {
            return this.assignPerdiem;
        }

        public void setAssignPerdiem(String assignPerdiem) {
            this.assignPerdiem = assignPerdiem;
        }

        @Column(name = "AssignAccOwner", length = 100)
        public String getAssignAccOwner() {
            return this.assignAccOwner;
        }

        public void setAssignAccOwner(String assignAccOwner) {
            this.assignAccOwner = assignAccOwner;
        }

    }
```

Comment: why don't you try : `entityManager.createNativeQuery("select a.AssignAccOwner,a.AssignBillRate,a.AssignPerdiem from orion_db.assignment as a where a.AssignmentId=?");` `q2.setParameter(1, 25);`

Comment: @AtimeneNazim I still got the same o/p

Comment: Can you post your assignement class ?

Comment: @AtimeneNazim I am using plain sql right so do we need to consider assignement class ??

Comment: You got a list of object so you manipulate object ! so i think that you have to consider Assignement class ! Because entity manager work with classes (objects)

Comment: @AtimeneNazim The entity class is very large so I have removed many fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the code issue , I was not connected to the local database and hence I was not getting the expected result..